# Find all files on server with 777 permissions

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, find, chmod

I'm looking for a Linux command to go through all the directories on my server and find all files with 777 permission. The output would be a list of all those files with full path.

Answer (score 65):

Use [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
find / -type f -perm 0777
```

Answer (score 17):

And if you like to find all files *without* Permission 0777 then just enter a ! before the perm, e.g.

`find / -type f ! -perm 0777`

Answer (score 9):

You can also change the permissions or ownership of all those files resulting from the `find` execution using the `-exec` option to avoid change them manually.

Example: In a web server you could need to grant the group to write files:

```
find /var/www/html -type f -perm 0777 -exec chmod 775 {} \; -exec chgrp www {} \;
```

Comment: Be very very careful doing this - always worth using -exec ls first in order to see what the effect of your command will do. Find is super powerful and will often find things you didn't expect it to.

Comment: It's true. My command should be used once you know which files will result from the search.

Answer (score 8):

it's as easy as:

```
find / -perm 0777
```

if you only want to match files, use this instead:

```
find / -type f -perm 0777
```